# ListView Navigation

Tags: android

I have a basic question. On the main screen there is a listview which should navigate to another listview. It is like selecting a category then a sub-category. For each subcategory view, should I create new activity or can I pass the position value from first listview to create the appropriate just once and can navigate back again ?

Comment: yes you can try searching you will get you answer

Comment: I searched before asked the question. If you don't want to answer just don't but don't give me advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using an `ExpandableListView` for your needs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/

http://android-adda.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

**UPDATE:**
to pass data to another activity you should do some thing like that:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = createIntentwithExtra(v, position);
    startActivity(intent);  
}

public Intent createIntentwithExtra(View v, int position)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TaskDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_ID, tasksRepository.get(position).getId());
    return intent;
}
```

**and in the second activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int taskid = bundle.getInt(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID);
```

same thing could be done with an array of strings.